# Set uid on directories

Tags: permissions, ubuntu-14.04, ls, setuid

I used chmod 4755 for a directory. Then, when I executed "ls", it showed drwsr-xr-x. I, however, reset its permission to 0755 and it kept showing drwsr-xr-x. I do not think "s" affects anything, but it is really weird.
How can I get rid of "s"? Or shouldn't I care about it?

My OS is Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the uid to a file or directory for giving the other users can access that directory or file as like the owner of that file or directory.  It will not make any effect. Other than the owner can access that.